# gnuplot - multiple lines from SQL query

Tags: sql, gnuplot

I'm wanting to plot multiple lines from the output of a SQL query which is generating output like the below. Anything with DB1 should be plotted as the first line, DB2 as the second line and so on. I've struggled to find a way to do this - there must be an easy way to do this?

```
DB1 01-Jan-2017 80.55
DB1 02-Jan-2017 90
DB1 03-Jan-2017 91
DB2 01-Jan-2017 50
DB2 02-Jan-2017 55
DB2 03-Jan-2017 52
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2) AS WHOLENAME FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

This will be added without any spaces though, so you can add spaces like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, ' ', field2)
```

etc.

This will get

```
Field1 field2
```

Hope this helps!